# Can nVIDIA GPUs store to memory from special registers?

Tags: cuda, ptx, nvidia-sass

I was fiddling with some SASS while looking into the way `%laneid` is used. After a gaffe which wasted a minute of someone's life (sorry about that - you know who you are), I now have the following:

CUDA code:

```
__forceinline__ __device__ unsigned lane_id()
{
    unsigned ret;
    asm volatile ("mov.u32 %0, %laneid;" : "=r"(ret));
    return ret;
}

__global__ void dummy(unsigned *C)
{
    C[0] = lane_id();
}
```

SASS (for SM 6.1):

```
    /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];            /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
    /*0010*/         {         MOV R2, c[0x0][0x140];           /* 0x4c98078005070002 */
    /*0018*/                   S2R R0, SR_LANEID;        }      /* 0xf0c8000000070000 */
                                                                /* 0x001ffc011e2007ff */
    /*0028*/                   MOV R3, c[0x0][0x144];           /* 0x4c98078005170003 */
    /*0030*/                   STG.E [R2], R0;                  /* 0xeedc200000070200 */
    /*0038*/                   EXIT;                            /* 0xe30000000007000f */
                                                                /* 0x001f8000fc0007ff */
    /*0048*/                   BRA 0x40;                        /* 0xe2400fffff07000f */
    /*0050*/                   NOP;                             /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
    /*0058*/                   NOP;                             /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                                                                /* 0x001f8000fc0007e0 */
    /*0068*/                   NOP;                             /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
    /*0070*/                   NOP;                             /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
    /*0078*/                   NOP;                             /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
```

So, the STG instruction - store to global memory I would guess - doesn't take SR_LANEID immediately, but rather the register into which it was placed by the inline PTX. Is this because (Pascal) GPUs can't store from a special register, or is it a missed optimization opportunity?

Comment: It takes a special operation (`S2R`) to read from special registers. Giving all instructions addressing modes to access special registers would counter the [RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computer) philosophy and IMHO would not be instruction bits well spent, given how likely such an operation is going to occur in practice.

Comment: @tera: Make that into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can't store from a special register directly; it takes a special operation (`S2R`) to read a special register's value.

Rationale: Giving all instructions addressing modes to access special registers would counter the [RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computer) philosophy and (in my humble opinion) would not be instruction bits well spent, given how likely such an operation is going to occur in practice.

Comment: And you know this for a fact? I mean, you're not just writing what you think makes sense?

Comment: I am just writing what I think makes sense. I don't know this for a fact, as SASS is undocumented apart from a [list of instruction names](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#instruction-set-ref) with a few words of description each.

Comment: So I +1'ed this but I'll not accept before I have some corroboration...

Comment: Fair enough - it was a comment originally... ;-)